# Ficus religiosa leaves turning brown and yellow

Tags: plant-health, leaves, bonsai, ficus, outdoor

Ficus religiosa leaves are falling off, some by turning yellow, and some by turning brown. I tried treating with fungicide thrice with 3 days gap in between, which is of no use. I use vermicompost as fertiliser, I added vermicompost to top layer soil. Still I notice the leaves turning brown. Kindly help me out.
The plant gets sunlight till 11a.m in the morning. And i water once in two days.
Im from India.
[image: leaf turned brown.]

Comment: There are what appear to be either tiny mites or tiny white eggs on the leaf surface - I can't tell what they are - if you have a magnifying glass, inspect the underside of the leaves closely. Is the plant in a pot or in the ground? Are you able to add a photo of the whole plant?

Answer (score -1):

Wash your plant, Get a damp rag and wipe the leaves.
Also, It grows in sandy loam that's well drained. Poke your soil to check for dryness... it may be underwatering, but as a tropical it needs plenty of light